# How to do GroupBy on complex object with an IQueryable

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm looking for a way to do a GroupBy on a complex object, instead of just one property. The trouble is that I want to do this on an **IQueryable**, because getting all the data from the table is a really bad idea in this case.

We're using Entity Framework 6.1.

The class looks like this:

```
 public class Pin {
   public Guid Id {get;set;}
   public Guid PageId {get;set;} /* this is the foreign key to our Pages-table */
   public PageClass Page {get;set;} /* this is a relation */
 }
```

I need to report on the times a certain page has been "pinned", printing the name of the page as well.

Right now my code looks like this:

```
var pinnedPages = GetAll().GroupBy(x => x, comparer);

foreach (var pinnedPage in pinnedPages)
{
    var numberOfTimesPinned = pinnedPage.Count();
    var pin = pinnedPage.Key;

    //write a line to the report
 }
```

But if I group on PageId, the `pinnedPage.Key` returns a Guid, obviously, while I need the whole `Page` object for my reporting needs.

I have tried implementing a custom comparer as well, but this cannot be translated to SQL, obviously which is why this doesn't work either.

Comment: Apparently, `GetAll()` returns `IEnumerable`. Can you get to the `IQueryable`?

Comment: And please also show the `Page` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
GetAll().GroupBy(x => x.pageId).Select(_ => new {key = _.Key, page = _.FirstOrDefault().Page, count = _.Count()});
```

This will group by on the pageId, however the select will create a new anonymous object which will contain the key (pageId) and select the first `PageClass` object

Comment: Just a note, the Grouping object already contains the grouped rows, so `var page = pinnedPage.First().Page;` in the foreach loop will also get the first page object. Including it in the Select will however leave more room for SQL optimisation, although I'd check for null before the grouping first (if relevant `.Where(x => x.Page != null)`) instead of returning empty page data with FirstOrDefault().

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any grouping if you query the pages directly and use a navigation property that I assume exist (or else should be added):

```
var pinnedPages = context.Pages
                         .Select(p => new
                                      {
                                          Page = p
                                          Pins = p.Pins.Count()
                                      });

foreach (var pinnedPage in pinnedPages)
{
    var numberOfTimesPinned = pinnedPage.Pins;
    var pin = pinnedPage.Page; 

    //write a line to the report
}
```

I use `context.Pages` because the source of the statement should be `IQueryable`. `GetAll` returns `IEnumerable` (apparently, otherwise the `GroupBy` overload with a comparer wouldn't work).